# Why is matchTemplate giving wrong matches at the image's center?

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I am using matchTemplate() in openCV to search within a small region of the camera's frame, lets say the 128x128 region in the top left corner for a smaller template image lets say of size 32x32.

I'm having a weird issue. When drawing the rectangle at the minLoc, I sometimes have perfectly smooth and normal tracking/matching, and therefore know that my code (mostly) is working.

The problem is however, I pick random templates to match on each initialize, and 90% of the time the center of the searchRegion is where the match is (incorrectly) detected. No matter where I move the camera, the center of the image is being 'matched' (with minor fluctuations at random points every so many frames).

Am I missing something about the way matchTemplate/normalize works? Why is the center of the src image wrongly being selected as a match?

Here is some code summarizing what I'm doing.

```
        Mat searchRgn = frame.submat(searchRgnRect);
        int result_cols = searchRgn.cols() - foi_img.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = searchRgn.rows() - foi_img.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows,result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

        Imgproc.matchTemplate(searchRgn, foi_img, result,Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1);
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
        //draw rectangle at mr.minLoc
```

Comment: post images and templates

Comment: you should not accept any minimum location but use a threshold to decide whether the minimum is small enough (before normalization)!

Comment: Make sure the 128x128 search region is from the second image you want to search in and not from the original image.

Comment: @Micka Sorry for the very late response, I've been busy. The images are from the source camera in android and it's therefore hard to share and test them. Can you explain how to set the threshold?